# Bootstrap-Table does not render the JSON data (but loads it successfully)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm tryig to use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) plugin to render my json data in a table. The data gets loaded successfully, however the plugin does not render the data into the table, it just says `No matching records found`.

I've been following the examples in the docs, tried to use methods like `load` and `refresh`, though according to [the example I almost copy-pasted](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html), you don't need to use any methods to load and render the data, you just have to specify either the `data-url` attribute in `table` tag, or add `url` property on a table object in your js file. I tried both variants and neither seemed to work.

Here's how I define my table:

```
<h1>Table</h1>
<div id="toolbar">
    <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        Delete
    </button>
</div>

<table
    id="table"
    data-url="/books/all"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-search="true"
    data-sortable="true"
    data-show-refresh="true"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-detail-view="true"
    data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
    data-minimum-count-columns="2"
    data-show-pagination-switch="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-id-field="id"
    data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
    data-show-footer="false"
    data-side-pagination="server"
    data-response-handler="responseHandler">
</table>
```

The `/books/all` returns the json data like this:

```
[{"id":42
    "name":"whatever",
"description":"whatever"
"cover_img":"https://whatever.jpg"
"available_count":10,
"price":6.99,
"author_id":21,
"publisher_id":5,
"author_first_name":"Harper",
"author_last_name":"Lee",
"author_birthday":"1926-04-27T22:00:00.000Z",
"publisher_name":"Penguin Fiction"},...]
```

I define my columns in js:

```
let $table = $('#table'),
    $remove = $('#remove'),
    selections = [];

const initTable = () => {
    $table.bootstrapTable({
        url: '/books/all',
        height: getHeight(),
        columns: [
            [
                {
                    field: 'state',
                    checkbox: true,
                    rowspan: 2,
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                }, {
                    title: 'Book ID',
                    field: 'id',
                    rowspan: 2,
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    sortable: true,
                    footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
                }, {
                    title: 'Book Detail',
                    colspan: 3,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    field: 'name',
                    title: 'Book Name',
                    sortable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter
                }, {
                    field: 'price',
                    title: 'Book Price',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    editable: {
                        type: 'text',
                        title: 'Book Price',
                        validate(value) {
                            value = $.trim(value);

                            if (!value) {
                                return 'This field is required';
                            }

                            if (!/^\$/.test(value)) {
                                return 'This field needs to start with $';
                            }

                            const data = $table.bootstrapTable('getData'),
                                  index = $(this).parents('tr').data('index');
                            console.log(data[index]);
                            return '';
                        }
                    },
                    footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
                }, {
                    field: 'operate',
                    title: 'Book Operate',
                    align: 'center',
                    events: operateEvents,
                    formatter: operateFormatter
                }
            ]
        ]
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
    }, 200);

    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
        'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
        () => {
            $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length);

            selections = getIdSelections();
    });

    $table.on('expand-row.bs.table', (e, index, row, $detail) => {
        if (index % 2 == 1) {
            $detail.html('Loading from ajax request...');
            $.get('LICENSE', res => {
                $detail.html(res.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
            });
        }
    });

    $table.on('all.bs.table', (e, name, args) => {
        console.log(name, args);
    });

    $remove.click(() => {
        const ids = getIdSelections();
        $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
            field: 'id',
            values: ids
        });
        $remove.prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $(window).resize(() => {
        $table.bootstrapTable('resetView', {
            height: getHeight()
        });
    });
};


function getIdSelections() {
    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), row => row.id)
}

function responseHandler(res) {
    $.each(res.rows, (i, row) => {
        row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1;
    });
    return res;
};
```

The `load-success.bs.table` event receives the data every time I refresh either the page or the table. The `responseHandle` function gets fired as well and receives the same valid data.

The JSON data format is valid and if I just copy the response from `/books/all` request and paste it to the `data` property in bootstrapTable initialization object (just after the `columns` property), the data will be rendered normally.

---

Could you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing additional info in the JSON where it specifies the number of rows, and encloses the actual data within a rows object, like:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "rows": [
  {
    "id":42
    "name":"whatever",
    "description":"whatever"
    "cover_img":"https://whatever.jpg"
    "available_count":10,
    "price":6.99,
    "author_id":21,
    "publisher_id":5,
    "author_first_name":"Harper",
    "author_last_name":"Lee",
    "author_birthday":"1926-04-27T22:00:00.000Z",
    "publisher_name":"Penguin Fiction"
    },
    ...]
}
```